# Process Explorer - How to make it point to local symbols

Tags: windows, debugging

I want to debug one of my exe's using process explorer for which I also have the associated pdb. However I am unable to make process explore pick up the pdb which is stored locally.

What I tried:
Updated the "configure symbols- dbghelp path" pointing it to 'debugging tools - dbghelp.dll' and in the symbol path gave the local folder path c:\symbols where i have placed by pdb's.

Is there any way we can make process explore pick up the local symbols?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To access symbols, you must have the Debugging Tools for Windows
Link:
[Debugging Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Go to PE Options->Configure Symbols, click Browse for dbghelp.dll:

- select architecture subfolder - x86 or x64. On default installation it is: c:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\

In symbols window you browse to pdb file folder of your app and that should be it.

Comment: On my system, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\dbghelp.dll` was the best value.  This cygwin command helped me find the latest one installed from any source (SDKs, Visual Studios, Windows Updates, etc): `find c:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\) -name dbghelp.dll -exec stat -t -c "%y %n" {} + | sort`